# How to automatically input text to the window program's text field

Tags: windows, java, python, c#

I think first i should know the window program's id or somthing .
Is it right? Or is there other way?
I will input the text file using python or something...
Let me know about it
Have a nice day
Thanks

Comment: Why did you tag your question java and C but not Python? Is any programming language OK?

Comment: Because this site does not offer phthon tag yet. I can handle java phthon c#

Comment: What is "phthon"? Please post the URL of a website talking about phthon, thanks!

Comment: Sorry that is a mistake ... did not catch it thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to fix it, thanks! Also, post a screenshot of the window showing the field to input text into.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thank you again . i fixed it. but the screenshot can not be opened .because it is not personnel thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily do this with AHK

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlFocus.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm

Example: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/97969-how-to-put-a-text-into-a-textbox-in-an-other-program/

I believe with some tabs and text input you will be able to do this easily and export the result into an exe file without the need of AHK being installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I always use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/) to automate any Windows tasks

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages.

I am not sure about AutoHotKey, but one big feature of AutoIt is that it will locate a window, or wait for it to become active. It doesn’t rely on X/Y coordinates, you can resize, move, or even minimize or hide  a program and your script will still run.

Here’s a simple script which opens Notepad, writes to its input and saves the file:

```
Run("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("This is some text.")
WinClose("Untitled - Notepad")
WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Save")
;WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Do you want to save") ; When running under Windows XP
Send("!n")
```