# Tool to automate login and workflow inside desktop application

Tags: automation

My project is into inventory domain, once order is created on the web/URL , need to login the desktop application to complete and fulfill the order.
I am using selenium web driver to create order on the Web.
What tool can i use to automate a desktop application? All inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Steps involved are:
1. To create an order on the web
2. To login a desktop application and complete the order.

Comment: Please write a better title, that reflects your needs.

Comment: Also, please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to create an automation script. One possibility (but not the only one, Google is your friend here) is the UIAutomation library, for which [I found an example here](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/desktop-application-ui-automation-with-powershell/).

I remember doing some simple automation without this library, so you might be able to find other approaches, but in any case: this can be done with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

For a few decades now, I have been using [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/), and can't recommend it enough for automating WIdnwos tasks. See, for instance [my answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/54770/how-to-automatically-input-text-to-the-window-programs-text-field/54790#54790) to [How to automatically input text to the window program's text field](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/54770/how-to-automatically-input-text-to-the-window-programs-text-field/54790) and search this site further for `autoit/

To quote that answer:

Personally, I always use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/) to automate any Windows tasks

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages.

I am not sure about AutoHotKey, but one big feature of AutoIt is that it will locate a window, or wait for it to become active. It doesn’t rely on X/Y coordinates, you can resize, move, or even minimize or hide  a program and your script will still run.

Here’s a simple script which opens Notepad, writes to its input and saves the file:

```
Run("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("This is some text.")
WinClose("Untitled - Notepad")
WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Save")
;WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Do you want to save") ; When running under Windows XP
Send("!n")
```

Comment: Five years later, and I am using AutoHotKey, which is a fork of AutoIt. Be sure to use v2, not v1. If your app uses WFP, then you need anotehr solution